# how to fix router.push() problem in vue-router , it is changing URL but not loading?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vite-plugin-pages

I have to refresh the page everytime when router.push() get called, I didn't have this problem , until I added second router.push(), I'm using vite-plugin-pages and vite-vue-layouts?

Comment: what do you mean you have to?  to do what?  what is your goal?  what is the technical problem? is there an error?  Explain **expected result** and also **actual result**.  Show all relevant code related to the problem as well.